# Unable to pass button event to Flask SocketIO to external python program

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have need to separate my python Flask web app and running code communicating via socketio. I'm able to get messages up from the external python program to the web, but I'm unable to get events from the web detected by the python program. In effect, I'd like when a user presses a button on a web page, for the external python code to print to terminal a hello world message. In the console for this html, I'm definitely seeing "Button pressed".

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listener</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect();

    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', 'yodle');
        console.log('Button pressed');
    });
});
</script>
<button id="mybutton">Push Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my basic Flask webserver code, which is working:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'froggy'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is my separate running program, which is not printing anything to terminal when the button is pressed:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(message_queue='redis://', host='0.0.0.0')

def my_function_handler(data):
    print("Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        socketio.on_event('my event', my_function_handler)
```

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something that is not supported. External processes can only emit, they are not recipients. If you need to emit and receive in the external process, then I recommend that you move the Socket.IO server entirely to this process.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this behavior is not supported in socketIO according to Miguel's answer, so I'm posting my particular solution to the problem if anyone is interested. I spent a lot of time Googling, Stack Overflowing, and generally falling down rabbit holes. What I ended up doing was that as I was using redis already, I just used it to pass messages between processes. There are a ton of general downsides to this approach, but it fits my needs nicely, so here's what I did. For index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Listener</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect();

    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.emit('button event');
    });
});
</script>
<button id="mybutton">Push Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'froggy'
app.debug = True
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')

r = redis.Redis("localhost")
r.set('button', 'not pressed')

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on('button event')
def handleMessage():
    r.set('button', 'pressed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Separate running process:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis("localhost")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        if r.get('button') == 'pressed':
            print("Button pressed!")
            r.set('button', 'not pressed')
```